# How to retrieve key/value from Dictionary, and combine them to a string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I tried to retrieve a specific pair from dictionary, and convert this pair into a string, like following one:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>();
        testDictionary.Add("3123", "1");
        testDictionary.Add("3523", "2");
        testDictionary.Add("5532", "1");

        string memberId="5532";
        string finalSelectedValue = testDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == memberId).Select(y => y.Key + "_" + y.Value).ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(finalSelectedValue);
```

However, I don't know how to implement the final step for combining Key and Value of this specific pair in the dictionary.

The expected result is: "5532_1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need LINQ here, **because dictionary cannot have duplicated keys**.  What you really need - just get entry by key and format its value (dictionary is very efficient with this task):

```
string memberId = "5532";
string value;

if (testDictionary.TryGetValue(memberId, out value))
{
    string finalSelectedValue = String.Format("{0}_{1}", memberId, value);
}
else
{
    // member not found
}
```

Less performant, but one-liner:

```
string finalSelectedValue = testDictionary.ContainsKey(memberId) ?
     $"{memberId}_{testDictionary[memberId]}" : null; // C# 6 string formatting
```

---

Why your approach didn't work? You are numerating all dictionary entries to find whether some key exists in dictionary (and that's a big overkill). `Where` operator will return you empty collection or collection with single entry (because dictionary cannot have duplicated keys). After that you are doing projection of filtered results to collection of strings (again one or zero items). And then you are converting collection to string - but that will return just type name of collection `IEnumerable<string>`. To fix your code you need to replace last `ToString()` with `FirstOrDefault()` and you will get single formatted string or `null` if entry not found. But.. see above :)

Comment: I like this solution. Clear and safe. No need to iterate through the keys and forego the whole efficiency piece of using a dictionary in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping the Linq and doing this:

```
string finalSelectedValue = memberId + "_" + testDictionary[memberId];
```

`testDictionary[memberId]` will return the value of the dictionary item `memberId`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
var finalSelectedValue = testDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == memberId).Select(y => y.Key + "_" + y.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalSelectedValue = string.Format("{0}_{1}", memberId, testDictionary[memberId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select` is going to return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`. Calling ToString on this IEnumerable is not going to give the results you were looking for. While it may be simple to just look for the key manually and get the value out, if you were looking for the linq solution here you would need to take a result by using a call which enumerates the returned enumerable in some way, such as `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, etc.

You could also just make a simple `Func` to do this. You should also probably define what happens when the key does not exist. I left it as a "?" here since it was not addressed in your post.

```
Func<Dictionary<string,string>,string,string> specificPair = 
    (d,key) => d.ContainsKey(key) ? key + "_" + d[key] : "?";
```

And then use it at will

```
string finalSelectedValue = specificPair(testDictionary,memberId);
```